# Use third party library in a angular factory

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, backand

This is my factory:

```
.factory('DataService',['$http',function($http, Backand ){
    var data = [];
    return {
        GetData: function(){
            return $http.get(Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/details').then(function(response){
                data = response;
                return response;
            });
        },
        GetElem: function(personId){
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                if(data[i].id == personId){
                    return data[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

}]);
```

Now the problem. The third party library `Backand`is correctly injected but i get the error: `Cannot read property 'getApiUrl' of undefined`

So Backand is undefined. When i use Backand in a controller everything work just fine.

What should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `Backand` while injecting

**Change this:**

```
.factory('DataService',['$http',function($http, Backand ){
```

**To This:**

```
.factory('DataService',['$http', 'Backand',function($http, Backand ){
```

Hope this will work for you.